# How do I make this login form smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have a login form on my website that I'm currently working on. The problem is that the whole thing is just to big. It is placed in the top right corner of my page, with the header in the middle and the menubar on the left upper corner.  Compared to the header and menubar it takes up to much space. I've fiddled with the css and html code for a while now, but I can't figure out how to make the "fields" or boxes where you write password and username smaller. Any suggestions?

```css
    form {
     float:right;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .login {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     right: 25px;
     font-size: 50%;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
    <span class='login'>
    
    <label for="E-mail">E-mail</label>
    <input name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" id="E-mail" />
    
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="Password" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </span> 
    </form>
```

Comment: We have no idea what your "header" or "menubar" look like. How can we possibly answer this question?

Comment: Simply play around with CSS values...

Comment: Hint: `input { max-width: 100px; }`

Comment: Its not really relevant what the header or menubar look like, regardless of where the login form is placed I simply want to change the size. But thanks for the help Maybe<3

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar to:

```
input {
    width: 50%;
}
```

You can also target only text type input fields with:

```
input[type=text] {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the `<span class='login'>` to `<div class='login'>`, It is not good span for this uses. And add this styles:

```
  form{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
  }

  .login{
     width: 50%; /* or any thing you need*/
     font-size: 50%; 
  }

  .login input[type=password]{font-size: 10px; /* or any thing you need*/}
```